# Upload Big Files(5GB to 5TB) using nodejs or something else

Tags: node.js, http, file-upload, upload, stream

i need to upload very big files using nodejs.(this can be changed to any language) i need a preferred method to do this. how google driver, dropbox, AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage etc upload much bigger files. is there any good reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
 npm install --save multer
```

It is nodejs package which stream the data over http and can upload large or small any kind of files to the server.
Here is a link to  the npm page:-

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.. i have used this and formidable. but something like dropbox etc do some thing else than this when they uploading files.. i am looking for that!